# Bootstrap menu delay on submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a slight delay on the third level of a dropdown using the bootstrap dropdown menu. Sorry I dont have a fiddle to show but the menu is this structure with products on the top menu dropping down to the list windows, doors, conservatories etc then items windows and doors have a submenu to the right at the third level..

products

|

WINDOWS

--> Casement

--> Tilt and Turn

--> Vertical

DOORS

--> Composite

--> French

--> Sliding

--> Bi-fold

--> Slide & Swing

CONSERVATORIES

ORANGERIES

TILED ROOF CONSERVATORIES

PORCHES

ROOFLINE

I have seen some useful javascripts

```
<script>
jQuery('ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu').hover(function() {
jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}, function() {
jQuery(this).find('dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

which is almost working but it shows both 3rd level menus when the parent is hovered ie when windows is hovererd the windows submenu shows then the doors submenu shows with the delay. Could anybody advise how to adapt the above code?

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="products.php" id="drop-mob" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="visible-xs"><a href="products.php">All Products</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a id="caret-one" class="trigger right-caret">Windows</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="casement-windows.php">Casement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tilt-and-turn-windows.php">Tilt &amp; Turn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="vertical-sliding-windows.php">Vertical Slider</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="caret-two" class="trigger right-caret">Doors</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="composite-doors.php">Composite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="french-doors.php">French</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sliding-doors.php">Sliding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bi-fold-doors.php">Bi-fold</a></li>
                        <li><a href="slide-and-swing-doors.php">Slide &amp; Swing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="conservatories.php">Conservatories</a></li>
                <li><a href="orangeries.php">Orangeries</a></li>
                <li><a href="tiled-roof-conservatories.php">Tiled Roof Conservatories</a></li>
                <li><a href="porches.php">Porches</a></li>
                <li><a href="roofline.php">Roofline</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```